# Calculating a group of tuples from a larger set so that the average number of occurrences of the members of the tuples are about the same

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on a problem that boils down to generating a "best fit" group of tuples so that each integer from 1-9 are present approximately the same number of times each, i.e, try to have 2 of every integer show up, or as close to this as possible.  For example if my groups were (1,4,9), (3,1,6), (1,2,3),(9,8,5), and (2,4,7), my summary would be as follows:
1- 3 occurrences
2- 2 occurrences
3- 2 occurrences
4- 1 occurrence
5- 1 occurrence
6- 1 occurrence
7- 1 occurrence
8- 1 occurrence
9- 2 occurrences

This is similar to a best sort algorithm I'm thinking, but I'm trying to wrap my head around what algorithm I should start looking at. As far as constrictions, each tuple would only consist of 3 members, and no integer can repeat within a tuple.  Any help as far as where to start looking or what direction to take will be greatly appreciated.

To better show what I'm trying to do, this is the check function I have so far.

```
   int CheckAverage(int *memberCount)
{
    int deviation = -1; //dummy number
    int sum = 0;
    int average=0;
    //memberCount hard coded to be 9
    for (int i = 0;i<9;i++)
    {
        sum += memberCount[i];
    }
    average = sum/9;

    //find the maximum deviation from the group

    for (int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
        int test = abs(average - memberCount[i]);
        if ( test > deviation)
            deviation = test;
    }

    return deviation;


};
```

With the array past being the count of the integers 1-9 as they appear in the group of tuples.  The goal is to get the returned deviation to be as close to 0 as possible.  So, for example, if I'm given the tuples (1,5,7), 
(2,4,5),
(9,4,3),
(5,3,6),
(2,7,3),
(4,3,2),
(6,3,1),
(9,1,5),
(2,1,3),
(7,1,4),
(5,2,7),
(4,3,1).  And I had to choose 5 from this set, what 5 would give me the value closest to  0 using my check function.  The main loop of the function would continue until the deviation is zero or it finds the set that gets the closest to zero.

I am just in the brainstorming phase of this problem at the moment and am asking for advice on how to tackle it, not outright code done for me.  The only way I've considered doing this so far is a brute force method of replacing each tuple one by one to see if the averages changed and iterate through the list multiple times till I've found the most optimal group.

Apologies if this sounds wierd. I'm still trying to find the best way to explain what I'm trying to do, and I'll provide clarification if needed

Comment: You could just generate an array of `n` uniformly distributed numbers using `rand() % 10` and put them into tuples afterward, skipping to the next element if a number appears twice.

Comment: Please give a few sample inputs (including edge cases), and desired output for each of these cases, plus an example of how you have tried to solve the problem and what problem you ran into.

Comment: Is a collection like (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9) acceptable?

Comment: say for example the goal was to have a group of 5 sets of tuples, and I have to choose from a set of 50 tuples so that I can get an average number of each integer 1-9 across those 5 tuples (ie each integer appears 2 times or such). Maybe thats a better way of explaining the problem.  The tuples are also set and cannot be broken up.  And yes, David, if the desired collection size is 6, that would be ideal as each integer appears 2 times.

Comment: So the problem is that those tuples may not be available?

Comment: I've editted my question some to hopefully better explain what I"m trying to do.  The main problem I"m having is trying to figure out the best algorithm for actually going through the list efficiently.  It may be that I have to use brute force, but was trying to see if there was a better algorithm to use

Comment: Generalized to arbitrary bases (i.e., larger than 10), it's at least as hard as the NP-hard [3D matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching). I'm not sure yet what to recommend.